How to access battery usage information of other apps/processes in Android?
I am writing an application in android studio, similar to a task manager, where you can choose a different running application, and you will get how much of the battery is being currently used by that application (in mAh or %). For example, you can choose the youtube application and get it's battery usage.
I have searched everywhere and I can't find how to get this information. I can access MY applications information, but not a different ones.
I thought of getting the cpu usage of the chosen app, but I also can't access that.
I would like it to work for the last three versions of android, but any solution is welcome.

The question is clear, but the title doesn't say what the question is about. Add "in Android" or so.

I've worked on a similar project for a while, from my experience, there isn't a proper way to do this. Your best bet could be to use the BatteryManager and get the current battery remaining energy multiple times while using the app you are monitoring. Keep in mind that the BatteryManager may not always be very precise depending on the device you are using.
Here is, in Java, how I used to get the current energy remaining, in mAh.
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.util.Log;

public long getPreciseEnergyCounter() {
BatteryManager mBatteryManager = (BatteryManager) context.getSystemService(Context.BATTERY_SERVICE);

Long energy = mBatteryManager.getLongProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CHARGE_COUNTER);
Log.d("energy", String.valueOf(energy));

return energy;
};

With this you can get an approximation of the energy used over time while the application is running. Note that it will be the total device consumption but I guess you could have an approximation of your app consumption by comparing discharge rate when the app is running and when it's not.
